# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtMaxNative

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, 3dsmax, shiboken2

Im trying to run a python(3.10.0) program in 3dsmax2024 which has Pyside2, shiboken2 (both 5.15.2.1). This errors shows up when trying to run a script:

```py
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in '_import' function
  File "<string>", line 8, in 'find' function
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\qtmax\__init__.py", line 12, in '<module>' function
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in '_import' function
  File "<string>", line 8, in 'find' function
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtMaxNative: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The issue comes from importing one of these:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtUiTools
```

Is there anything im missing like two libraries colliding with imports or something? :)

Thanks

**Steps i have taken:**

- Reinstalling 3dsmax2024
- Clearing everything in the site-packages folders
- Adding libraries one by one

Comment: 3ds ships with their own version of python and pip, and their build of Qt/Pyside. You're not trying to update PySide on your own, are you? Because that error makes me think that the script is trying to import a PySide module that does not match the Qt version that is currently running in 3ds.